# Recovering files from IIS system (inetsrv) directory?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, data-recovery

Some file from my inetsrv directory (c:\windows\system32\inetsrv) were accidentally removed. Is there a way to get them back? Reinstalling IIS server role doesn't help, because Windows doesn't remove inetsrv directory when removing the role. Copying files from another Server 2008 machine doesn't help neither.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the files from another server should work, but it would have to be at the same patch level.

Have you tried removing the role, manually deleting the directory and then adding the role back?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it. I remove a role and then get an error trying to install it.

Answer (score 1):

What files specifically are missing? If it's administration.config or applicationHost.config from the inetsrv\config folder, you can find a copy of them in C:\inetpub\history in any one of the CFGHISTORY folders that should be there.

---

Looking at that directory on a W2K8 server without IIS installed shows an empty directory.
On a W2K8 server with IIS freshly installed with only the default features selected shows this:

http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/7253/inetsrv.jpg

Comment: I don't know what files exactly are missing. I want to get the initial state of inetsrv folder, as it was before IIS was installed for the first time. Is there any way to do that except for the system reinstallation. What "the clear state" should be?

Comment: Okay, I have completely removed inetsrv and inetpub folders and now trying to install IIS role. It's taking a bit long...

Comment: Nope... Even with inetsrv and inetpub folders uninstalled IIS role refuses to install any of the components.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind losing your IIS sites & settings and starting again, uninstall IIS (which will leave the `inetsrv` folder as it is) and then follow the instructions in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/132114/uninstall-iis-on-windows-7) to zap `inetsrv`. When you re-install IIS, it will re-install the necessary files/folders in `inetsrv` and you will have a blank IIS installation once again.