# Uninstall IIS on Windows 7

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7

I've just rebuilt my development machine and installed IIS. I then installed the Web Deployment tool and used this to restore my previously-backed-up websites to the clean machine. Unfortunately the restoration didn't work correctly/fully.

I couldn't easily correct the problem, so I decided to uninstall/reinstall IIS and recreate the sites manually.

I uninstalled IIS and rebooted, but there was still plenty of stuff left around such as various files in `/windows/system32/inetsrv/` which I tried to delete manually (with limited success!).

I rebooted again and tried to reinstall IIS - it reported an error (no meaningful message) and requested another reboot. The event log includes the following errors:

```
The World Wide Web Publishing Service (WWW Service) did not register the URL prefix http://*:80/gallery for site 1. The site has been disabled.
```

and

```
Unable to bind to the underlying transport for [::]:80. The IP Listen-Only list may contain a reference to an interface which may not exist on this machine.
```

I'd like to avoid another rebuild. Can I *completely* remove IIS, such that I can reinstall it from scratch? Or can I 'fix' the current setup so that IIS will reinstall over what is already there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to delete the conetents `INETSRV` folder, thanks to this page:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-delete-a-system-file-in-windows-vista/

I actually had to modify the `cacls` command slightly to handle folders rather than files (/T switch, if I recall correctly).

Once the folder was cleared, IIS could be reinstalled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is not IIS Installation issue. Check this article [KB 890015](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/890015). Check the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters` by default there is no `ListenOnlyList`

Comment: I'm afraid it is an IIS installation issue. I've resolved the two errors above (thanks to your link), but the problem remains - unfortunately when the installation of IIS fails there doesn't appear to be a meaningful error recorded anywhere. Elsewhere on the internets, other people with similar problems have resorted to a rebuild. This is the second time I've used the Web Deployment Tool and this is the second time it has failed me. :(