# how to uninstall iis on windows 7 enterprise

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, iis, visual-studio-2010

I have googled and looked into this site. Reviewed the following post here on SF

[Uninstall IIS on Windows 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/132114/uninstall-iis-on-windows-7)

I have done all the research before posting this question so please do not down vote.

But I still do not know **how to uninstall iis completely on my local dev machine**. I would like to get very step by step instructions.

My machine setup is as follows:

Windows 7 Enterprise

Service Pack 1

64 bit OS

Visual Studio 2010

Enterprise Service pack 1

IIS version 7.5

Please help.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uhh...

1. Start
2. Control Panel
3. Programs and Features
4. Turn Windows Services On or Off
5. Uncheck Internet Information Services
6. Click Ok

Am I missing something?

Comment: I already did that .. but I am not sure if this would completely un-install iis from my dev machine.